# Winforms label text not showing completely

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Here is the code I am using to add a label to a simple form:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "Hello how are you This is an example label in my first form";
myLabel.Location = new Point(50,20);
```

Here when the form is run, the label shows up, but partially, the all text does not show. How to make the full label text show up in the form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can give us more context around your label? Give a wider sample of code and perhaps a screenshot so that we can have a visual of what is the problem.

Comment: Hi @pensum the problem appearantly has got solved after addition of the property AutoSize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `AutoSize` property. By making that `true`, the label text will automatically size and completely show up. Add this:

```
myLabel.AutoSize = true;
```